# Can hyperlink text contain both words and decorative images?

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility

I know it's technically possible to have a single hyperlink contain both text and an image:

```
<a href="http://example.com/user/profile">
    Joe Bloggs
    <img src="http://example.org/decorative-image.png">
</a>
```

Is there a reason (HTML spec, accessibility etc) why links shouldn't contain both text *and* images together? I'm wondering if it would be better to output the image *after* the hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://example.com/user/profile">
    Joe Bloggs
</a>
<img src="http://example.org/decorative-image.png">
```

In my case, the decorative image is just a green circle which indicates the user is online right now.

Comment: I don't know of such a reason and actually it's the preferred way. Think of file downloads which contain an icon to indicate the file format.

Comment: @Paul I'm imagining a PDF icon after the download link, but can't remember if the actual icon is also linked.

Comment: I guess there are various ways to implement it, inside the link, outside or as a background image. Bottom line was, I don't see any valid reason to not include both image and text inside a single anchor element.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the image inside the link is better because it represents the relationship between the decorative image and the link more accurately.

It also increases the size of the click target, which is good for users with motor control issues.

That being said, you must add an empty (null) alt attribute to the image tag to communicate that it is decorative to the assistive technologies.

```
<a href="http://example.com/user/profile">
    Joe Bloggs
    <img alt="" src="http://example.org/decorative-image.png">
</a>
```

An alternative would be

```
<a href="http://example.com/user/profile">
    Joe Bloggs
    <img src="http://example.org/decorative-image.png" role="presentation">
</a>
```

Comment: I think in OP’s case the image isn’t decorative, as it "indicates the user is online right now", which is relevant information. So the `alt` value should be something like "currently online".

Comment: @unor You are right, if the information is not included in the text, it is not decorative.

Answer (score 0):

You are perfectly ok to wrap a link tag around text and images.